# Not able to connect to apple tv !! "Making apple tv ready for development" dialog shown

Tags: ios, xcode, tvos, apple-tv

I'm trying to connect apple tv with my xcode to debug my app. But I'm getting [below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPDMC.png) dialog and it will never go. So I tried following steps to fix but no use.

1. Waited for 10 mins and checked but still the same.
2. I restarted/reset apple tv and checked but no use.
3. Tried with different versions of xcode but no use.
4. Tried using wifi, mobile hotspot with different networks.

[image: Screen shot]

Some times I will get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePdNE.png) dialog and it will never go.

[image]

If I try to run app in this state then I will get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZO14.png) alert in xcode

[image]

So I'm not understanding the why its behaving like this. And how to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

**Wireless Debugging on Apple TV**

[Dive](https://stackoverflow.com/users/186529/dive) has some great recommendations about using Apple TV with your machine, connected via Ethernet. So far this is also my preferred way to connect, develop and deploy to Apple TV, however debugging on Wifi isn't the best experience.

Here are a few things you could try.

1. Remove current pairing by using Device and Simulator window.

   [image]
2. Try downloading [Apple Configurator 2](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12) and use that to first pair your Apple TV to your machine. This is great tool to ensure you can connect to your iOS/tvOS devices for some super user type setup.  ( Main Menu -> Paired Devices)
   For this to work you have to be on a specific screen on your Apple TV.
   *Settings -> Remote and Devices -> Remote App and Devices* ( This uses multipeer connectivity)

[image]

[image]

3. If you are successful pairing your TV using apple configurator then it's a good sign as you can rule our networking issues with your Wifi.
4. Try pairing with Xcode after it's paired with your machine in the step above. The dialog window you see above is expected and takes some time ( longer in some cases) but should eventually complete.
5. If step 3 wasn't a success, unpair from Xcode and Apple Configurator ( if they show as connected but not aren't really paired), restart your machine and Apple TV and start the same steps again.

**Lan Set up :**

1. You can connect to your Apple TV via a switch or usually Modem/Routers have inbuilt switch ( extra ethernet ports).
2. Try the same steps and you should be able to pair with Xcode.

**Troubleshooting:** Try using Console app on your machine if you still can not figure out the root cause and this should help you debug the pairing issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is a helpful instruction from Apple - [Pair a wireless device with Xcode (iOS, tvOS)](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/9.0/index.html?localePath=en.lproj#/devbc48d1bad) and I assume that you did as they recommend.

Such issues usually appear due to the following reasons:

- Something is wrong with your network configuration. The easiest way to check is to try to wirelessly connect your iPhone to be sure that you do not have the same problem. If this is the case then try to white-list the IP address for the Apple TV on your router and open necessary ports;

  - About port, Apple recommends the following configuration: Communication to network devices uses port 62078. Some networks block specific ports. You may need to check your network settings or ask your system administrator to open this port;
- Your Xcode version has to be in sync with tvOS. From the screenshots, I see that you have tvOS 13.3.1. It means that it is better to use Xcode 11.3.1 in this configuration. But you mentioned that you already tried this.

The [option](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/9.0/index.html?localePath=en.lproj#/devac3261a70) that always works to me is to use an Ethernet connection. I connect my AppleTV via the ethernet cable to my router and access it from my MacBook without problems:

- Connect the device to the same network using an Ethernet cable.

  - For an Apple TV, connect using the Ethernet port in the back of the device.